# Lilypond bar line before clef

Tags: lilypond

I want my scores to have a bar line on the start of each new line. Currently, at the beginning it is just open (see yellow part in the image).
Is it possible to achieve this bar line with lilypond?

```
\version "2.22.2"

\relative {
  \repeat unfold 100 {
    c'4
  } 
}
```

[image: lilypond]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bar line can be seen when you have multiple staves on one system. These things are called *system start delimiters* and exist as line, as brace, as bracket and as square. If you look here

https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/internals/system_002dstart_002ddelimiter_002dinterface

you’ll see that these have a property `collapse-height`. If you look here

https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/internals/systemstartbar

you’ll see that for SystemStartBar this has a default of 5 staff space units. If the height is smaller then this the start delimiter will not be printed. To force a different behavior just change this value:

```
{ c d e }

\layout {
  \override Score.SystemStartBar.collapse-height = #-inf.0
}
```

Edit: To get the SystemStartBar without rounded corners you’ll need to change the way it is drawn (there is no parameter to specify roundedness). One quite simple way would be to take the original stencil and replace it with a box of the same dimensions (the original stencil itself is simply a rounded box).

```
\layout {
  \override Score.SystemStartBar.stencil =
  #(grob-transformer 'stencil                                           ; Change stencil depending on original stencil
                     (lambda (grob orig)                                ; grob is a reference to the SystemStartBar-object, orig is the original stencil
                       (if (ly:stencil? orig)                           ; collapse-height might lead to the grob suiciding during calculation of orig, in that case there is no original stencil
                           (let ((xext (ly:stencil-extent orig X))      ; X dimensions of original stencil
                                 (yext (ly:stencil-extent orig Y)))     ; Y dimensions of original stencil
                             (make-filled-box-stencil xext yext)))))    % Create a filled box of same dimensions
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works good after changing `#-Inf.0` to `#0`. Otherwise I get a warning and no effect.

Comment: @Guest Sorry, should of course have been `#-inf.0`. No idea how this got through ...

Comment: Thanks that works! Unfortunately Lilypond draws the starting bar different (rounded corners and all others without rounded corners; can be seen when colored), but I try to solve this or ask this in a new question.

Comment: @Guest Hm, the regular BarLine is indeed not rounded, but usually it is shortened by half a line thickness to each side, so the end of the Staff line will produce such a rounded effect. For some reason I do not know coloring the BarLine makes it longer so that this does not apply anymore. If you want to have the look of a BarLine you should also consider increasing `\override Score.SystemStartBar.thickness = #1.9`.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will consider this!

Comment: @Guest The amazin Jean has shed light on this issue on the mailing list. Basically the slight shortening of the bar line if no color is specified is done as else rounding errors can lead to a slight protrusion of the bar line beyond the staff especially on display.

Comment: Thank you for the information. When explicitly say `\override Score.SystemStartBar.rounded = ##f` lilypond ignores this. But it detects `rounded` as a valid field and also checks the data type. When I rename it to `roundedd` or so, it will yield an error. Also, if I set an other data type. So, when I explicitly disable rounded corners, it should not draw it rounded, I think. But it does, unfortunately. Can be seen also when `\override Score.SystemStartBar.color = #green` (assuming layer of the staff lines at lowest with `\override Staff.StaffSymbol.layer = #-1`).

Comment: @Guest The reason for this is that while the grob property `rounded` exists by default the stencil for SystemStartBar does not make any use of this property. Instead you’ll need to change the stencil for the SystemStartBar althogether, as I’ll demonstrate in an edit.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the additional edit to show how to edit the stencil! I tried this before using simple commands but had no luck. Your code works as expected! Now, I can see what you meant with "slight protrusion of the bar line" (with SumatraPDF, with Adobe Reader it's fine), but that's ok so far :)